# Algorithm: how many indivisible units are needed to overshadow a random number?

Tags: c#, algorithm

How can I find how many indivisible units of `1,000` are needed to overshadow a random number?

For example, for random number `5,123` I'm going to need `6` x `1,000` to overshadow it, so: `MyAlgorithm(5123, 1000) = 6`

Edit1: I am sorry if despite my endeavor to articulate my problem into a meaningful description my dyslexia took over, I hope this edit makes it a bit more comprehensible.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: What is an abstract number, an indivisible unit, and what does it mean to cover?

Comment: @sircodesalot an abstract number is a number that cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Ah, ok he wants to map a value-pair of abstract numbers, then perform a surjective reduce of the projected result onto an indivisible unit. Got it.

Comment: Is this question asking how to implement the "round up" function? @sircodesalot I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Restating the question in entirely opaque language. It's a joke. Although if you have to explain it, I guess it's not that funny : /

Comment: Considering I don't see how those words make any sense, I can't tell if it's funny.

Comment: Incorrect terminology ("abstract") typically leads to confusion ("abstract" may actually partly make sense, in theory, but has a different meaning in OOP). If there's even the slightest possibility that the general programming community won't understand a term you use, it's best avoided or explained. And do try to respond to comments in a timely fashion. After 3 hours, most people probably would've given up on waiting for a response (to a comment posted by someone else) - you really should plan to stick around for at least 1/2 hour after asking a question.

Comment: @Dukeling as a dyslexic I find it hard to even reply to your comment, you are right, the words I chose didn't fit and the result was awful no matter how many times I had to review it before posting. Regarding the second part of your comment, I got back as soon as I could, I also have to work to make my living.

Comment: @tnw nothing that would compile :(

Comment: @sircodesalot I edited my question, I hope it makes more sense now and BTW I liked your joke :)

Comment: @G.Bach You are right, my words didn't make any sense, I hope the edit made it a bit more comprehensible.

Comment: @DougPeters I was actually referring to the comment by sircodesalot; I just assumed that I was simply unfamiliar with the terms you used. Didn't mean to cause unease. Are you maybe trying to implement the "round up" function?

Comment: @G.Bach thank you for clarifying this, yes I guess this is another version of the `round up` function and I'm sorry I put you guys in all that trouble trying to figure out what it was that I was trying to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I understand your question, it sounds like you could simply convert the parameters to decimals, divide, then use [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cz5da1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int output = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)5123 / (decimal)1000); // 6
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the conversions and rely purely on integer division and the [% operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) (modulus), like this:

```
int output = (5123 / 1000) + (5123 % 1000 == 0 ? 0 : 1);
```

If you want this in a method simply wrap it up like this:

```
static int MyAlgorithm(int a, int b)
{
    return (a / b) + (a % b == 0 ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if I've understood you correctly, this is really just a one-liner:

```
public static int MyAlgorithm(int input, int units)
{
   return input%units == 0 ? input/units : input/units + 1;
}
```

the only case when it isn't simply the result of `input/units + 1` is the case when there is no remainder

Answer (score -1):

```
public int MyAlgorithm(int x, int y)
{ 
     int result = x / y;
     return (result < 0) ? (result - 1): (result + 1);
}
```

Comment: No explanation? If it works, why does it?

Comment: What do u need me to explain? My algorithm is so simple to read.

Comment: It's always good to add a sentence or two explanation, even if you think it's obvious. Oh, and, perhaps more significantly, this doesn't deal with the case when `x` is perfectly divisible by `y` correctly.

Comment: I am sorry, this doesn't seem to work when `x = y`, thanks for trying though.